# How to ignore files grunt uglify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

**Background**

I've just started using grunt as of about 30mins ago. So bear with me.

But I have a rather simple script going that will look at my js and then compress it all into one file for me.

**Code**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            options: {
                beautify: true,
                report: 'gzip'
            },
            build: {
                src: ['docroot/js/*.js', 'docroot/components/pages/*.js', 'docroot/components/plugins/*.js'],
                dest: 'docroot/js/main.min.js'
            }
        },
        watch: {
            options: {
                dateFormat: function(time) {
                    grunt.log.writeln('The watch finished in ' + time + 'ms at' + (new Date()).toString());
                    grunt.log.writeln('Waiting for more changes...');
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: '<%= uglify.build.src %>',
                tasks: ['uglify']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch');

}
```

**Question**

My main.min.js is getting included in the compile each time. Meaning my min.js is getting 2x, 4x, 8x, 16x etc etc. Is best way around this is to add an exception and ignore `main.min.js`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

To the **end** of the src array, add

```
'!docroot/js/main.min.js'
```

This will exclude it. The ! turns it into an exclude.

http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand

> Paths matching patterns that begin with ! will be excluded from the returned array. Patterns are processed in order, so inclusion and exclusion order is significant.

This is not specific to grunt uglify, but any task that uses grunt convention for specifying files will work this way.

As a general advice though I would suggest putting built files somewhere else than your source files. Like in a root `dist` folder.

Comment: thanks very much, I had thought that as it happens. But still, good to know :)

Comment: just wanted to highlight the importance of **end** bit once more

Comment: End here is very important. Agreed @trkaky

Comment: Hi there, this does not seem to work with a src file mask `path/to/files/**/*js` . Therefore `src: ['web/js/**/*.js', '!web/js/bin/file1.js', '!web/js/bin/file2.js']` does not ignore file1.js and file2.js . Have you ever encoutered this problem? is it because i am trying to ignore files in a subfolder?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo To exclude multiple files when using a src file mask. I simply put the excluded files into an array at the end of the src. src: ['web/js/**/*.js', ['!web/js/bin/file1.js', '!web/js/bin/file2.js']] That worked just fine for me