# How do I manage external libraries from bower in grunt?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower

Currently I have bower putting all my lib files into: src/libs

I have grunt reading all files in src folder and minifying.

this seems like a lot considering the libraries are already minified, should I just point bower to my dist folder?

Will it still work if I keep them in src?

Comment: Have you tried excluding the bower libraries from grunt minifying?

Comment: How exactly? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: In your GruntFile.js you can configure grunt. Locate anything with "min" and exclude the directory like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453974/how-to-ignore-files-grunt-uglify)

Comment: ok, so how do I still include them?

Comment: Excluding them from minifying doesn't exclude them from other grunt tasks. If you want to exclude the libraries but include some of them, google on `grunt minify exclude directory` and `grunt minify include directory`. Or you could give us the GruntFile.js so we can edit that.

Comment: Its easier just to point bower to dist/libs

Comment: If you do that, don't forget to exclude libs from grunt clean task.