# How works "except" attribute in Grunt Uglify?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I am trying to minify all my javascript files with [Uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify), less jQuery and Modernizr files. I am using the attribute "except" inside the mangle options, writting jQuery and Modernizr, but it isn't work and everything is minifyed.

Here the Uglify options that I have in the Gruntfile.js:

```
options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n',
        mangle: {
          except: ['jQuery', 'Modernizr']
        }
  },
```

I have tried to put the name of the files jquery.min and modernizr.custom, but it doesn't work.

**Resolved!** Thank you Jashwant for your fast comment. Sorry for that, I didn't check fine the related questions.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453974/how-to-ignore-files-grunt-uglify) help ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Jashwant! I didn't check fine the related questions, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Jashwant I could resolve the problem. He link to me a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453974/how-to-ignore-files-grunt-uglify) where the solution was put **!** before the files that I don't want to minify. Something like this:

```
'!library/js/libs/jquery.min.js'
```

Thank you!